# Xcode 12.5: target ‘PACKAGENAME’ has invalid header layout

Tags: xcode, xcode12, swift-package-manager, xcode12.5

When attempting to add or resolve some ObjC packages (for example, [TZImagePickerController](https://github.com/banchichen/TZImagePickerController.git)) using Xcode’s frontend to SPM, a compile error occurs like this:

```
target ‘PACKAGENAME’ has invalid header layout: umbrella header found at '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-fpcffpkaycriklgbcfxqlgkqjolr/SourcePackages/checkouts/PACKAGENAME/PACKAGENAME/PACKAGENAME.h', but directories exist next to it: /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-fpcffpkaycriklgbcfxqlgkqjolr/SourcePackages/checkouts/PACKAGENAME/PACKAGENAME/PACKAGENAME.bundle; consider removing them
```

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is just **installing [Xcode 12.4](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)** and using that instead of 12.5.

No idea why this is happening, but I did submit a feedback about it: [FB9097550](https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/205).